# Real-time processing using Kafka, Storm & HBase

Tags: hbase, apache-kafka, apache-storm

Apologies for my ignorance.

We are building a real-time database that captures records based on members  activity on a website. The application that emits these information is IBM MQ. We are planning to setup Apache Kafka to consume these messages from IBM MQ and store that in HBase for Analytics. Is it possible for Kafka to write this information directly into HBase OR we should a setup a real-time stream engine like Apache Storm in between Kafka & HBase? That is Kafka --> Storm --> HBase.

Appreciate your valuable feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka is just a publish-subscribe messaging system for real time activity. So it just receives and sends. Main features are messaging in realtime, fault tolerant and large scale data processing.

To perform actual processing, you have to depend on Storm. On one side of Strom, you take kafka output and on the other side, you can have data processing and send the data to hdfs or hbase. Its upto you. The topologies(storm jargom) run forever which is one of the main requirement for real time unlike batch processing

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need to use Kafka and Storm to write data to HBase. As per my understanding, you can write the data directly from IBM MQ consumers to HBase.
 HBase has java api. It also has Thrift. So, other languages like Python, Ruby, etc can also talk to HBase.